# I Am Getting Device error and cordovajs 404 error?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to the angular and ionic, i am trying to get device information i wrote the code for that and also i gave the links and added libraries and also i run this (cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device) command before generating apk file, and i installed that in mobile but it is not getting device information can u please tell me is  there any problem i add the code bellow what i wrote?

```
    <!--INDEX file-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

       <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

        <script src="Module.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="DeviceController">
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">Device Information</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li class="item">
                            Manufacturer : {{manufacturer}}
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            Model : {{model}}
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            Platform : {{platform}}
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            UUID : {{uuid}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
    </html>

    <!--Module.js -->
    var deviceTracker = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
    })

    <!-- Device tracker Controller -->
    deviceTracker.controller('DeviceController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaDevice) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
    // sometimes binding does not work! :/
    // getting device infor from $cordovaDevice
    var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
    $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
    $scope.model = device.model;
    $scope.platform = device.platform;
    $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
    });
    });
    })

I am Getting an error Like this....

GET http://127.0.0.1:49943/cordova.js 

angular.min.js:102 ReferenceError: device is not defined
    at Object.getDevice (ng-cordova.min.js:7)
    at app.js:26
    at l.$eval (angular.min.js:125)
    at l.$apply (angular.min.js:126)
    at app.js:23
    at Array.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:48811)
    at onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js:2447)
    at onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js:2428)
```

Comment: Any screenshots of your error and steps you took to resolve? Is your project working without the device plugin?

Comment: first when you create new project with ionic command `ionic start prjname templatename` you do not need to add device plugin it is already added to it.

Comment: yes i have but i don't have permissions to send screen shot -Gene

Comment: @amorbytes   i think i didn't add device plugin can u tell me where i add device plugin....

Comment: open you ionic project in terminal. and run this command

`ionic plugin ls`


add output to question so we can review your plugin list

Comment: as you new I would like to help you with some ionic cheatsheets have a look over it


## http://devdactic.com/ionic-cheatsheet/
## https://medium.com/@petehouston/ionic-cheatsheet-67151f0297a4#.nfa8f8c5r

Comment: @amorbytes ----thank u

Comment: have you got resolved your problem ?

Comment: ya my problem is resolved..thank u alll..........